# Building sequence of axiomatizable classes that...

Tags: model-theory

Any tips how to build sequence of axiomatizable classes *$\mathrm{K_0, K_1, ..., K_n, ...}$* that class $\bigcup_{n\in w}\mathrm{K_n}$ is not axiomatizable?

Comment: What is the definition of axiomatizable?

Comment: What about $K_n=\{A:\|A|\le n\}$?

Comment: Please tell us your thoughts so far :)